# Protobuf-net doesn't generate the file "TypeModel.cs"

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

All day I've tried using protobuf-net package with hope, but I haven't succeeded. In detail, the steps I have done to try to run the code:

1. Download NuGet the protobuf-net (version 2.0.0.668) package.
2. I put the following lines of code at the beginning of my program:

   ```
   using ProtoBuf;
   ```
3. The code to classes are:

   ```
   [ProtoContract]
   class Person {

       public Person(int id, string name, Address address)
       {
           this.Id = id; this.Name = name; this.Address = address;
       }

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return "\nPerson.ID" + this.Id + "\nPerson.NAME = " + this.Name + "\nPerson.ADDRESS >> " + this.Address.ToString();
       }

       [ProtoMember(1)]
       public int Id {get;set;}
       [ProtoMember(2)]
       public string Name { get; set; }
       [ProtoMember(3)]
       public Address Address {get;set;}
   }
   [ProtoContract]
   class Address {

       public Address(string line1, string line2)
       {
           this.Line1 = line1; this.Line2 = line2;
       }

       public override string ToString()
       {
           return "\n\t\tAddress.Line1 = " + this.Line1 + "\n\t\tAddress.Line2 = " + this.Line2;
       }

       [ProtoMember(1)]
       public string Line1 {get;set;}
       [ProtoMember(2)]
       public string Line2 {get;set;}
   }
   ```
4. The execution code to test the serialization is:

   ```
   var person = new Person (12345, "Fred", new Address ("Flat 1","The Meadows"));
   //
   using (var file = File.Create("person.txt"))
   {
       // I think it works well (in the txt, file is displayed)
       Serializer.Serialize<Person>(file, person);
   }
   //
   Person newPerson;
   using (var file = File.OpenRead("person.txt"))
   {
       // EXCEPTION: 'ProtoBuf.ProtoException' in protobuf-net.dll
       // INFO: No parameterless constructor found for Person
       newPerson = Serializer.Deserialize<Person>(file);
   }            

   MessageBox.Show(newPerson.ToString());
   ```

**IMPORTANT**: When I did these steps for the first time and I compiled the source code, a dialog box with a file **TypeModel.cs** *appeared on screen but then suddenly disappeared*. I have reviewed several forums and I have a sneaking suspicion that **protobuf-net** automatically generates **TypeModel.cs**. *If this is my problem, how I can resolve it? How I can get protobuf-net back to ask me where I want to save the file **TypeModel.cs**?*

Comment: _No parameterless constructor found for Person_ say that in serializable class should be parameterless constructor, in your person class you have only one constructor with two params, so add default constructor like `Person(){}`

Comment: Your response has been excellent aid, has solved my problem. I can't believe I've been all day for this ... Why protobuf-net works this way?

Comment: i'm not sure, but possibly it too hard create instance with custom parameters, and better ask about it @MarcGravell :-)